# Is it allowed to have two 144-hour visa-free transits in China within a short period?

Tags: transit, china, visa-free-entry, french-citizens

I am making some travel plans around Christmas and I may attempt two visa-free transits in China within a short period of time. E.g., some airport X outside Mainland China -> CAN -> some airport Y outside Mainland China for a short time, either a few hours or a few days -> CAN -> some airport X outside Mainland China.

Is that ok, or will my second attempt to enter China via visa-free transit be rejected on the grounds that I was recently granted a visa-free transit? If that matters, I'm a French citizen. More generally, I'd be interested to know the limitations on how many visa-free transits can be granted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen anything in the policy that precludes this. A few hours could be considered as suspicious, but a few days will be fine.

As far as I can tell from the policy text, as long as you check all the boxes, passport from the right country, flights in a triangle, etc, you're eligible.

Of course, final decision always lies with the Immigration officer.

**UPDATE:**

The Chinese government has [announced](https://www.chinadaily.com.cn/a/202311/24/WS6560552ea31090682a5eff22.html) visa-free entry for up to 15 days for 6 countries, including France, from December 1, 2023 to November 30, 2024. This kinda solves the issue for the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Follow-up questions: [How can I get notified when I am allowed visa-free entry to a country, or conversely, when I am not allowed anymore to enter a country visa-free?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/184767/1810) and [Why is China allowing visa-free entry for citizens of France, Germany, Italy, the Netherlands, Spain and Malaysia?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/82853/2231)