# How can I get notified when I am allowed visa-free entry to a country, or conversely, when I am not allowed anymore to enter a country visa-free?

Tags: online-resources, visa-free-entry

I [read](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/184755/1810):

> The Chinese government has [announced](https://www.chinadaily.com.cn/a/202311/24/WS6560552ea31090682a5eff22.html) visa-free entry for up to 15 days for 6 countries, including France, from December 1, 2023 to November 30, 2024. [Author: [dda](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/138870/dda)]

This makes me wonder: How can I get notified when citizens of a given country become allowed visa-free entry to a country, or conversely, when they are not allowed anymore to enter a country visa-free? Assume that we are considering the average citizen, not some corner cases (e.g., convicted felons).

---

As a French citizen, I looked at my country's official site for travelers but they don't seem to provide that information. https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/dernieres-minutes/, they don't mention the new Chinese policy on allowing French visitors without visa for 15 days. https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/conseils-par-pays-destination/chine/#entree also is still missing that information and still states "A visa is required for French nationals." ("Le visa est obligatoire pour les ressortissants français.")

Comment: Wikipedia notification is probably the most accessible way. Else specialized press and newsletters. Or if you think it is useful and it may have market, you can just create a webpage for that (and scanning every day official websites).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks, Wikipedia notification is a good idea, you're welcome to post it as an answer.

Comment: That's the responsibility of your government. Have you checked the French MFA announcement?

Comment: I wonder why the downvotes. This is most definitely an interesting question, and seems to be answerable.

Comment: I wonder if there are interfaces to Timatic or Traveldoc which would allow you to get such notifications. I wouldn’t be surprised if they existed but were available only to people “in the business” and/or with an expensive subscription.

Comment: @jcaron I imagine absolutely zero evidence of any attempts of prior research has something to do with that

Comment: Does your country of citizenship offer a country-specific updates advice notification service, such as [Foreign travel advice](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice) for British citizens, for example?

Comment: @Traveller Thanks, good idea, I found an update advice notification service called "Fil d’Ariane" on https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/conseils-par-pays-destination/ (I am a French citizen) but it seems it only gives update for a specific destination and not all possible countries. I also don't know if it gives updates pertaining to visas.

Comment: @Traveller Looking at https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/dernieres-minutes/, they don't mention the new Chinese policy on allowing French visitor without visa for 15 days. https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/conseils-par-pays-destination/chine/#entree also is still missing that information and still states "A visa is required for French nationals." ("Le visa est obligatoire pour les ressortissants français.")

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer for China, my main country in terms of visa requirements. I have subscribed to a few accounts on social media, from a visa agency in Shanghai on WeChat, to Chinese news outlets on Twitter. For instance, I learned about the visa-free arrangement for 5 EU countries + Malaysia on the day of the annoucement from 3 different sources, within 10 minutes.

Wikipedia might have some stuff for some countries, but for countries of interest I'd dig around for social accounts (official, visa specialists, etc).

Comment: This is based on the destination country, while I believe Franck is interested in learning about new opportunities for visa-free travel (to any country which until then required a visa), for people of a given nationality (and vice-versa when visa-free travel ends).